# fs.copy fails with large number of images, works for small number

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, asynchronous

I have an array of filenames that I am trying to copy from one directory to another. The filenames are constructed in functions within an `async` `series` chain, then in the final function, they are copied using `fs.copy`. The script operates on ten different directories as well, so what I have looks like this. It's simplified, but the functionality is identical.

```
var dirs = [{
    'src': 'dir1',
    'dest': 'dest/dir1',
    'files': []
}, {
    'src': 'dir2',
    'dest': 'dest/dir2',
    'files': []
}, {
    'src': 'dir3',
    'dest': 'dest/dir3',
    'files': []
}, {
    'src': 'dir4',
    'dest': 'dest/dir4',
    'files': []
}];

async.series([function(callback){
 //get files
 dirs.forEach(function(currentSrc){
    fs.readdirSync(currentSrc);
 });
 callback();
},
function(callback){
  //make dest dirs with dirs.forEach and fs.mkdir
  callback();
},
function(callback){
  var src
    , dest;
  dirs.forEach(funtion(dir){
    dir.files.forEach(function(file){
      src = path.join(dir.src, file);
      dest = path.join(dir.dest, file);
      fs.copy(src, dest, {replace: false}, function(err) {
        if (err){
          console.log('error copying file: ', err);
        }
    });
  });
}]);
```

This works fine for small number of files, however when I tried it with directories containing around 400MB, it failed. All the files appear to be in the destination, but there is do data there beyond the names (which are correct), but the filesize of each is 0. Why would this work for a small amount of files, but not large?

Update. I get the error

> events.js:85
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Update:
I'm now using a strategy provided by @Jacob and what I have is this:

```
var dirs = [{
    'src': 'src/1',
    'dest': 'waterfallDest1',
    'files': []
}, {
    'src': 'src/2',
    'dest': 'waterfallDest2',
    'files': []
}, {
    'src': 'src/3',
    'dest': 'waterfallDest3',
    'files': []
}, {
    'src': 'src/4',
    'dest': 'waterfallDest4',
    'files': []
}];




async.eachLimit(dirs, 1000, function (dir, cb) {
    async.waterfall([
        function (cb) {
            fs.mkdir(dir.dest, cb);
        },
        function (cb) {
            fs.readdir(dir.src, cb);
        },
        function (files, cb) {
            async.eachLimit(files, 10, function (file, cb) {
                var src = path.join(dir.src, file);
                var dest = path.join(dir.dest, file);
                try { // In case fs.copy is indeed throwing an error
                    fs.copy(src, dest, {replace: false}, cb);
                } catch (err) {
                    cb('try-catch err ', err);
                }
            }, cb);
        }
    ], cb);
}, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Some error happened:\n' + err.stack);
    }
});
```

This is creating all the directories successfully, and transferring files into the first directory, successfully, however every subsequent directory is filled with 0k images.

Comment: I'm curious why you're using `readdirSync` since you're using `async` already.

Comment: @Jacob That is probably a remnant of something i I had earlier. I'm quite new to all of this. How would you suggest i do it?

Comment: Maybe a limit of 1000 is too many since it'd be 1000x10 (concurrent files) = 10,000 files being copied in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

You need a final callback for your `async.series` call:

```
async.series([
  function (callback) {
    dirs.forEach(function (currentSrc) {
      fs.readdirSync(currentSrc);
    });
    callback();
  },
  function (callback) {
    //make dest dirs with dirs.forEach and fs.mkdir
    callback();
  },
  function(callback) {
    var src, dest;
    dirs.forEach(funtion(dir){
      dir.files.forEach(function(file){
        src = path.join(dir.src, file);
        dest = path.join(dir.dest, file);
        fs.copy(src, dest, {replace: false}, function(err) {
          if (err){
            console.log('error copying file: ', err);
            // Did you want to do callback(err)?
          }
        });
      });
    })
    // Somewhere, this needs to call back.
  }
], function (err, result) {
  if (err) {
    // One of the steps had an error; handle it.
  }
});
```

Here's how your code could use `async.each` to avoid all these loops. It also includes limits to avoid the OS opening too many files at once:

```
async.eachLimit(dirs, 10, function (dir, cb) {
  async.waterfall([
    function (cb) {
      fs.mkdir(dir.dest, cb);
    },
    function (cb) {
      fs.readdir(dir.src, cb);
    },
    function (files, cb) {
      async.eachLimit(files, 10, function (file, cb) {
        var src = path.join(dir.src, file);
        var dest = path.join(dir.dest, file);
        try { // In case fs.copy is indeed throwing an error
          fs.copy(src, dest, {replace: false}, cb);
        } catch (err) {
          cb(err);
        }
      }, cb);
    }
  ], cb);
}, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Some error happened:\n' + err.stack);
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks. "Somewhere this needs to call back." Would since `forEach` in synchronous, maybe that's the problem. Perhaps I can replace it with `async.each`? If that is the case, where would the callback go?

Comment: I notice you just pass `cb`s as parameters to the various functions, yet never call them. Is that intentional?

Comment: In the case of `async.each`, `async.waterfall` will call the callback. Similarly, the other callbacks are passed to async functions, which will take care of calling them. You only need to call the callback if something else isn't already doing so.

Comment: I've implemented the waterfall solution you provided me. thanks! however, only files are transferred into the first directory successfully. After that, the subsequent files seem like they're in their respective `dest` dirs, but it's just the names. All 0K. I've updated my question with what I've got currently. Do you think you could take another look?

Comment: Also, is this method of not explicitly calling the callbacks standard? On the async API, callbacks are explicitly called at the end of each function.

Comment: One last thing: is this `eachLimit` loop's second parameter the api just says "limit". Is that like it will process ten until fully done, then begin a new batch? Thanks once more.

Comment: It will process a maximum of 10 in parallel at a time; once one finishes, it will pick up another. I think in this case, if you limit both `each` with a 10, there'd be a maximum of 100 files being copied at a time.

Comment: The callbacks should all be getting called, either directly or by being passed to an aync function. Will look at your update.

Answer (score 0):

Per [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) "You can use try/catch to handle exceptions or allow them to bubble up."

```
  try {
    fs.copy(src, dest, {replace: false});
  } catch(e) {
    if ( e.code != 'EEXIST' ) throw e; // I'm guessing here that this
                                       // is your problem.
  }
```

For what it's worth, the underlying library ncp is to blame for sporadic callbacks within fs.  [fs issues](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/issues/98)  **IF** ncp behind-the-scenes has called a callback more than once for a single file then the second callback would throw an exception that... the file already exists.

Comment: Thank you. What would this error mean? That the file simply doesn't exist? Why wouldn't that just be handled in the `cp` callback?

Comment: Hi. The `try-catch` block did not produce any errors. The error I am getting `ENFILE, open` then the name of one of my files. Do you know what that could be? Is it like opening the file is part of `cp` and that's failing. If so it's curious that my `try-catch` didn't catch it.

Comment: `ENFILE` means `File table overflow`; you probably have too many files open at the same time. See my update for using `eachLimit` to avoid too many concurrent tasks.

Comment: try-catch won't work for asynchronous errors. (And even if it did, simply catching the error and ignoring it would not be the correct solution.) `error` events on any event emitter by default cause an exception to be thrown - see https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_events_eventemitter . If you had access to the event emitter in question you could catch it by setting an `error` handler. But I don't see how you can, which looks like a shortcoming of `fs` to me. Jacob's solution (`async.eachLimit`) is probably the next best thing.

Comment: @Thomas  Oh good, you finally have a useful error now with ENFILE.  As Jacob has suggested, there's an open file limit and you've exceeded it.  One good thing about node is that it can scale well.  One bad thing about node is that it can fire off multiple things that can hit limits like this.

Comment: @MichaelBlankenship is there any way to increase the limit, or pause execution until the files are closed and start a new batch?

Comment: @Thomas The maximum open files per user per session is rather large already.  It might be something like 16,384 on a Windows computer and probably similar for a UNIX box.  I think it would be considered bad form to try to open more since it starves the systems involved of resources.  Search StackOverflow for "how to slow down a javascript loop" to see how you might use setTimeout().  Make sure to test your Ctrl-C exit handler thoroughly after doing so since these scheduled threads might surprise you.